# LUT - Maximum error of linear interpolation approximation

Tags: thermistor, resolution

I'm currently using an LUT (Look-Up Table) stored in a microcontroller, to read the temperature from an NTC sensor. I'd like to achieve a precision which is known, it doesn't matter if it is not so high.

The first step in which I'm stuck is to know well the error introduced by evaluating an interpolation of two values in a LUT.

What I thought: If the LUT have 1°C steps, the maximum error using the intermediate value as discriminant, is 0.5°C. And (what I thought) the only final solution to this is that I can print on a display the value interpolated (i.e. 24.8°C) instead of the LUT (i.e. 25°C), but both have 0.5°C of error. The case of 24.8 +- 0.5°C it doesn't seems so meaningful. Maybe 24.5°C could be a better solution.

The second thought is that interpolating using two points separated by 1°C, are bringing an error which can be smaller than 0.5°C, since it is related to the ratio of second derivative of the curve and a factor of 1/8 times the step of the function (here 1°C) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_as_approximation). But I'm not sure at all of what I am reading: supposing that I have the Steinhart-Hart equation, I do not have the second order derivative. Am I right? Any suggestion? Is this analysis necessary to make a correct estiamtion of the error?

Comment: What is an LUT?

Comment: Edit just made.

Comment: Why not just work out the error for an insanely sampled set up points, and take the maximum?

Comment: Taking the maximum is ok if I know what I am doing. The risk  of your proposal is to obtain a final error that is insanely high or erroneously low. That why I need a tiny bit (just a bit) of math to be solved.

Comment: My suggestion will give you a map of your actual error at many points, as finely grained as you want.  Do with the data what you like, you don't need to take the maximum, but the method is guaranteed not to provide an erroneously low number.

Comment: FWIW, I think this should be migrated to math.

Comment: Why negative votes?

Comment: Probably http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/observation-on-user-voting-statistics. I gave you an up to compensate because I though your question(s) in this thread were quite competent. While it is a more math-y question than others, it's not just a question of interpolating some data (in contrast with http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192838/gnu-octave-how-to-find-interpolate-values-from-a-file), so I don't think it should be migrated to math.SE by the way (@Scott Seidman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve is smooth and monotonic, hence the maximum error is 0.5 degrees C.

The derivative of the function will give you the slope, higher order derivatives are necessary to find the maximum error. You could fit a cubic spline (matching the slopes on either side of the area of interest) to the data points and evaluate the maximum error analytically, but frankly it would be a much better approach to simply evaluate at a much finer resolution than your desired accuracy, just as @Scott suggested in his comment

Suppose you don't care about anything finer than 0.1°. You can easily evaluate over the entire range to 0.01 or 0.001 degrees C on a PC in seconds. The maximum error in those calculations will be +/- 0.005 or +/-0.0005 degrees C respectively, since the curve is smooth and monotonic at any resolution.

Doing an simple brute-force exhaustive search will provide confidence on the maximum error. Unless your range is very narrow, or your ADC very fine resolution, you'll probably run into resolution errors with a typical thermistor long before you have unacceptable linearization errors.

Comment: I presume that sampling to obtain the table will require a measurement set-up with a tolerance far smaller than what I obtain from the NTC. The table that I'm using is provided from Vishay. But if this is not present, I can use the Steinhart equation and sampling its plot (and the DS provides also the error provided by the function, which will sum on the others).

Comment: The datasheet values are probably calculated by S-H or extended S-H, not measured. You can test that the values agree.

Comment: ...agree.... but I need a correct evaluation of the T(R) function first. It is a circular problem! :D
What is S-H?

Comment: Steinhart-Hart. So you use Steinhart-Hart and verify that the values agree with the table in the datasheet first.

Comment: For what concerns the 0.5°C error introduced, if I don't re-evaluate a S-H equation, the final tolerance of my system will be 0.5°C plus the error of the model which is affected by the tolerance of the NTC? This error is not so low and is usually reported on datasheets, and is like a bowtie: http://product.tdk.com/en/techjournal/tfl/sensor_actuator/NTCG2/images/001e_p1_gla.gif
Of course I'm talking about precision on an high range, i.e -40 to 120°C

Comment: Yes, the sensor tolerances will affect the system error.

Comment: I also presume that I can't put the sensor in a melting ice and removing the eventual offset.. or, despite the non linearities of the NTC, for what concerns the error, once it is find for the individual sensor, can be removed or at least reduced without re-evaluating the SH terms?

Comment: Oh, you could add a simple offset or a 25°C offset + span (gain) diddle term to the linearized temperature output without changing the SH terms, but at some point a better sensor is the right way to go. Especially since we don't have a good model of what unit-to-unit variations look like beyond the 'bowtie' chart. Probably a 'beta' variation models it, but that's inside info at the thermistor maker. Often we require interchangeability and don't want to add stuff that can screw up the reading worse than the factory calibration so we don't even try.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. So I have two possible paths. If I want interchangeability, I can't even re-evaluate the coefficients. If I don't need that, I can remove the component error by re evaluating the 3 points of temperature (except for the error inside the 3 points measured): in this way I can also remove the whole partition error and ADC, except for any ADC non linearities. Did I forget anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Your error depends HIGHLY upon the nature of the underlying function.  Even so, your error for a 1 degree table should be SUBSTANTIALLY less than 0.5 degrees.  In fact, under your conditions, I think the expected value of the error even if you just take the nearest point with zero interpolation (a zero order approximation) is 0.5 degrees.

Comment: That is exactly what I said. For this reason I was trying to see how much less than 0.5 could be.

Comment: @thexeno, it could be a great deal higher than 0.5 if the function is not well behaved-- but an NTC sensor will not be that badly behaved.